# search for double-braced text or double parentheses using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to select the values ​​that are in a string between double parentheses and double-braced but that allow non-double braces and parentheses

I used the following expression for the double-braced but it is broken if it has a braced inside the string. this should only be broken by having double-braced, but I do not know how to make the regular expression

```
/{{([^}]*)}}/g
```

and

```
/\({2}([^)]*)\){2}/g
```

I tried adding double-braced here, but it does not work:

```
/{{([^}}]*)}}/g
```

Comment: Would `{{stringhaving{{doublebraces}}` be allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you want to permit single braces inside, you shouldn't use a negative character set - instead, start at the left delimiter and lazy-repeat any character until you get to the right delimiter. For example:

```
/{{(.*?)}}/
```

```js
const pattern = /{{(.*?)}}/g;
const str = 'foo{{bar}} foo{{baz}} foo{{with}bracket}}';
console.log(str.match(pattern));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the backslash in your parentheses.

Maybe something like `/\{\{([^)]+)\}\}/` would work

Example:

`console.log("{{TEST}}".match(/\{\{([^)]+)\}\}/)[1]);`

`console.log("{{TE{{}}ST}}".match(/\{\{([^)]+)\}\}/)[1]);`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

what @certainperformance said is correct.
I just want to add a expression for both parentheses and braces as you asked for in question.

**You can try this for both parentheses and braces **

```
((?:{{)(.*?}}))|((?:\(\()(.*?\)\)))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/M0UvUM/5/)

```js
const regex = /((?:{{)(.*?}}))|((?:\(\()(.*?\)\)))/gm;
const str = `foo{{bar}} foo{{baz}} foo{{with}bracket}}

foo((hello))


test{{test))

{{test))
{{test}}
((test))
test))
`;
let m;

let op = str.match(regex);
console.log(op);
```

Comment: That also matches `{{test))`

Comment: @Thefourthbird oh yeah i misplaced alternation and was wondering why it is not working :p Anyway good catch :)